# How to Uglify/Minify an Angular App when deploy to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to minify all the .js and .css files from my application.

**1. What I've already done:**

`server.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/my_app'));

// Send all requests to index.html
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/my_app/index.html'));
});

// default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

**2. Setting the `start` and the `postinstall`** on `package.json`

```
"start": "node server.js"
"postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
```

Then I deploy my app to Herokuapp. The uglify and the minify has not been applied in those files.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="1">
    <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
```

Comment: This link proved the most helpful for a ReactJs app. https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/tutorial-how-to-deploy-a-production-react-app-to-heroku-c4831dfcfa08